Why is LoadAsync returning incorrect data from DynamoDB?
I'm trying to create a Dictionary app API using AWS that can Load a dictionary entry from DynamoDB.
The problem is that when I try to GET a dictionary entry from the DB using LoadAsync, all of the correct data is returned except in one property, which is a list of objects called "definitions." LoadAsync even returns the correct number of objects in the "definitions" list, but each object is empty.
I tried to build and run my API locally and then send it a GET request using Postman. I expected it to have all of the same data as I can see on the DynamoDB Console, but it is missing data in each of the objects in the "definitions" property.
Here's a picture of some of the data from the AWS Console, notice the definitions objects have data:
DynamoDB Console
And here's a picture of the result in Postman when I make a GET request, which calls LoadAsync (notice the empty objects in the list of "definitions"):
Postman

Those aren't the same item. Can you make sure you look at the same item in the console that it has values for the map?

they certainly are the same item @LeeroyHannigan, the "word" property is the key and these have matching "word" values. I know for a fact they are the same because every other item in my table has only "word" and "dateAdded" values.
the problem is that when I GET the item, it has the correct number of values in the "definitions" list, but is missing data in that list's maps.
